How can I combine two partially completed rows in google sheets based on matching ID value?
We are using a two-part google form in which you will fill out either the full form or part of the form, depending on the status of what we're studying.  If you only fill out the first part, you would have to go back later and fill out the second part.
So for example I have columns A-E and I filled out in part A
Column A, then Columns F-I filled out in part B.
I want to merge these rows based on matching value in column A, replacing the empty values in F-H in the first instance with the values from second instance, then merge column I to have both values.
In this sample doc, I would want line 3 and 5 to merge, and line 1 and 6 to merge.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hHDq515kIhzEy1EG1iqqqRCMDCtLMl5fZmnS5iRUHN4/edit?usp=sharing
I got this partially working on my work computer but it put a bunch of blank cells between the OG values and the merged value. Please help!
I tried to use =map and some formulas I found on the internet but it didn't work well. I can't show exactly because I can't log into this from my work computer. :)

are you looking for a formula or script bcoz formulas cannot merge rows in the way you were describing; at best they can produce an output in a separate column range while the input data remains as-is in  columns A-I

Literally any way to make them work. I don't mind producing an output in a separate column range as long as it matches columns A-I

Can you add/showcase your ideal expected output separately (by entering it manually) so that I can get a clear picture on what is expected here?!

Sure! I updated the sheet linked above... I have Sheet 1 which would be the first set of data we would acquire, and then sheet 2 which would be collected at a later date for the same "case." "Final" is what I'd like it to look like. Thank you! Not every "case ID" Will have data entered for the second half, and it may not be done in order.


You may try:
=map(unique(tocol({Sheet1!A2:A;Sheet2!A2:A},1)),lambda(Σ,hstack(Σ,ifna(xlookup(Σ,Sheet1!A:A,Sheet1!B:E),wraprows(,4,)),xlookup(Σ,Sheet2!A:A,Sheet2!B:D,))))


